# phpQuery > FATAL ERROR

Tags: php, phpquery

Пытаюсь сделать парсер на phpQuery, получаю DOM документ через:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use PhpQuery\PhpQuery;

$pq = new PhpQuery;

$hbr = file_get_contents('https://snipp.ru/demo/76/index.html');
$dom = $pq->newDocument($html);
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PhpQuery\PhpQuery::newDocument() in Z:\domains\neowin\1.php:8 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in Z:\domains\neowin\1.php on line 8
```

Comment: нет метода newDocument() в классе PhpQuery

Comment: Я уже нашел документацию, но там выводится через var_dump, а как вывести чистый текст элемента не было, не подскажите - как?

Comment: если я правильно понял через print_r() , а вообще мне кажется вот что Вам надо https://habr.com/ru/post/471644/

Comment: во первых newDocument статический метод, вызывается через ::

Comment: @AlyanFery Попробуйте `$elem = $pq->find('#elem'); $text = $elem->text();`, в документации всё есть и html и как найти дом элемент и прочее

Comment: Dmitry, в phpParser отсутствует newDocument, а эта статья по нём

Comment: @RifmaMan, такая же ошибка только с find

Comment: `$dom = phpQuery::newDocument($hbr);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$hbr = file_get_contents('https://snipp.ru/demo/76/index.html');
$dom = phpQuery::newDocument($html);
```

или

```
$hbr = file_get_contents('https://snipp.ru/demo/76/index.html');
$dom = PhpQuery::newDocument($html);
```